# getting error in VM during flume command execution

Tags: flume-ng

i am getting this exception in my VM after running the flume coomand in my Vm-flume-ng agent -n agent1 --conf ./ -f spoolagent.

the error is as follows-

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/flume/node/Application : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

give me a proper soulution for VM on linux sysytem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Comment: please give me the proper solution for VM and how to fix it in VM

Comment: The problem is that you use a java jre version too old. 
To correct your problem, install java jre 8 or later in your VM

Comment: i already have that jre version 8 in my vm